# Trying to make AMF3 Packet

Tags: c++, apache-flex, amf

I'm trying to make AMF Packet. I'm using https://github.com/Ventero/amf-cpp C++ implementation of AMF3, but it doesn't contains all needed variables.
AMF0 documentation is describing how is built AMF packet (http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/amf/amf0_spec_121207.pdf)
First two bytes specify packet version:

> version = U16
>   It could be 0 or 3

U16 is an unsigned 16-bit integer in big endian 
(network) byte order

So i created

```
typedef unsigned int u16;
```

In amf.hpp
I'm trying now to add all header information to single std::vector variable.
I wrote:

```
std::vector<u16> buf = std::vector<u16>{3};  //packet version
std::vector<u16> buf2 = std::vector<u16>{0}; //header-count
std::vector<u16> buf3 = std::vector<u16>{1}; //message count

std::vector<u16> data;

buffermain.insert(data.end(), buf.begin(), buf.end());
buffermain.insert(data.end(), buf2.begin(), buf2.end());
buffermain.insert(data.end(), buf3.begin(), buf3.end());
```

In result in data i just have first inserted vector(buf).

//edit
I made some progress.

```
Serializer serializer;
QByteArray outArray; //to insert amf bytes, and send it later

AmfArray Content;
AmfObject Object;

Object.addSealedProperty("Source", AmfNull());
Object.addSealedProperty("operation", AmfNull());
Object.addSealedProperty("clientId", AmfNull());
Object.addSealedProperty("destination", AmfNull());
Object.addSealedProperty("messageId", AmfNull());
Object.addSealedProperty("timestamp", AmfNull());
Object.addSealedProperty("timeToLive", AmfNull());
Object.addSealedProperty("timeToLive", AmfNull());
Object.addSealedProperty("body", AmfNull());
Object.addSealedProperty("headers", AmfNull());

Content.push_back(Object);
serializer << Content;

std::vector<uint8_t> data2 = serializer.data();

char* datas = reinterpret_cast<char*>(data2.data());//

std::vector<unsigned __int32> v;
v.reserve(data.size());

char* sizes = reinterpret_cast<char*>(v.data()); //teoretical size of message in U32

char null = 0;
outArray.append(null); //version first byte
outArray.append(3); //version second byte
outArray.append(null); //header count first byte
outArray.append(null); //header count second byte
outArray.append(null); //messages count first byte
outArray.append(1); //messages count second byte

outArray.append(null); //"Target" lenght first byte 
outArray.append(4); //"Target" lenght second byte 

outArray.append(QByteArray::fromHex("6e756c6c")); // "Target" value

outArray.append(null); // "Response" length first byte
outArray.append(2); // "Response" length second byte

outArray.append(QByteArray::fromHex("2f31"));

outArray.append(sizes); //insert theoretical length of message
outArray.append(datas); //insert message
```

Comment: Did you have a question?  I think you've done a good job of explaining what you're trying to do; but I'm unclear what the problem is.

Comment: Well AMF (0 or 3) ist usually just the encoding of the data. Especially every AMF3 message is wrapped in an AMF0 message that has the AMF3 content in a specially excaped portion of the AMF0 message.  In thid AMF3 payload usually Adobe doesn't directly encode your payload. It's usually encapsuled in AMF3 serialized command objects. I once did a complete reverse-engineering of AMF3 communication. Unfortunately I am currently unable to find that document ... will give it another look when I'm at home.

Comment: @Reboog711 i described code, i just don't know why buffermain contains only first inserted value (buf), it should contains buf, buf2 and buf3.

Comment: @chrisdutz Thanks, and i would be grateful for your next info :)

Comment: I have experience with RTMP/AMF and I honestly can't see what the problem is.. Please make it a clear question. What is the problem? What exactly happens? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Using edited code i'm receiving: http://scr.hu/0tgp/hsifg
What i wanted to receive: http://scr.hu/0tgp/mkugt

Comment: Properly code in hex: http://pastebin.com/FBe4rmZB and my code in hex: http://pastebin.com/kYKjSfwY

Comment: From what you posted so far I can surmise that your Serializer class is returning invalid data. But that's as far as I can go without looking at the sources.

Comment: I think that i bad enumerate length of message. (char* sizes), but i don't know other way. Serializer is good, because when i sent just Content i could decode that http://scr.hu/0tgp/kra5d

Comment: So how to write in U32 lenght of my amf message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm the author of [amf-cpp](https://github.com/Ventero/amf-cpp))

I've just added AMF3 packet support to amf-cpp. To use it, you have to create an `AmfPacket` object, add headers (`PacketHeader`) or messages (`PacketMessage`) and then serialize the `AmfPacket`. Here's a quick example (which assumes something like `using namespace amf;` for brevity):

```
AmfPacket packet;
// first, we construct a simple header in-place
packet.headers.emplace_back(
    "SomeHeader", // header name
    false, // must understand?
    AmfString("Value") // header value
);

// set up the message value
AmfObject object;
// add some properties
object.addSealedProperty("prop", AmfString("val"));
AmfArray content;
content.push_back(object);
// now construct the message in-place
packet.messages.emplace_back(
    "com/example/Object.method", // target uri
    "/1/onResult", // response-uri
    content // value
);

// amf::v8 is a typedef for std::vector<uint8_t>
v8 data = packet.serialize();
```

The resulting `data` object can then be used with your `QDataStream`.

In the future, if you notice that amf-cpp is missing a feature you would like to use, feel free to open a bug report on the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/Ventero/amf-cpp/issues).

Comment: @Ventero I am having an inspection on AMF3 packet using Charles. And trying to recreate the packet using your amf-cpp library. Thanks to your job, first. But I am finding it that what I have created is different from captured by Charles. Do you have any good example of your library? Your answer to this question does not tell me much about your library.

Comment: And when I post it to the server using libcurl, I get this message from the server. /3/onStatus
CrootCausemessagedetails code?There was an unhandled failure on the server. java.lang.NullPointerException#Server.Processing

Comment: @JoshuaSon As this library is still under heavy development and the API is still subject to change, I don't have any documentation yet. Any chance you could create a bug report on the Github tracker (https://github.com/Ventero/amf-cpp/issues/) with some more details on what packet you're trying to recreate? Also, I'm not sure how libcurl comes into play here, as the serialized message is supposed to be sent over a socket.

Comment: @Ventero Thanks. I will keep looking at that Github tracker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QDataStream](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatastream.html) to output your data in network byte order.

```
QDataStream stream(&outArray, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
stream.setByteOrder(QDataStream::BigEndian);
stream << (qint16)3; // version
stream << (qint16)0; // header count
stream << (qint16)1; // message count
stream << (qint16)4; // target length
stream << (qint32)0x6e756c6c; // target
stream << (qint16)2; // response length
stream << (qint16)0x2f31; // response
stream << (qint32)data.size(); // message size
stream.writeRawData(data.data(), data.size()); // message data
```

I recommend switching all of your I/O code to use QDataStream to interface with QByteArray instead of writing out each byte individually.